# Requiring a separate require.js app

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have two require.js apps. The second uses the first one as a dependency. It looks like that:

in app1/main.js

```
requirejs.config( {
    baseUrl : 'js', // baseUrl relative to app1 folder
    paths: {
        // paths used for app1
    }
});
requirejs(['module'], function (module)  {
    return module;
});
```

This file needs to be completely "standalone" and has its own require config so it can load its module and libs.

Then,
in app2/main.js

```
requirejs.config( {
    baseUrl : 'js', // baseUrl relative to app2 folder
    paths: {
        'app1' : '../app1/main' // Using the other app
    }
});
requirejs(['app1', 'module'], function (app1, module)  {
    console.log(app1, module); // The first one should be app1/module.js, the second app2/module.js
});
```

This second file need to have its config, but also needs to load app1/main.js as a dependency like it was a usual module.

but the two requirejs.config just get mixed and if I require a file in the first one it uses the baseUrl of the second, or other problems like that.

So:

- How can I turn a require.js app into a loadable module that keeps its own config?
- Is it possible to do this without building before? (I need to work on both at the same time and I'd prefer not to have to wait for builds each time I change something)
- I read about namespaces which maybe is a solution but didn't see anything about how to use them for these sort of cases - If I have to add them manually at the start of my files it's not a problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing to your second app's configuration, as I understand. I belive, you should separate your **configuration** and this **app1module** module. Then you will be able to require your **app1module** wihtout **configuration** part.

In other words:

**app1/main.js**

```
requirejs.config( {
    baseUrl : 'js', // baseUrl relative to app1 folder
    paths: {
        // paths used for app1
    }
});
```

**app1/module1**

```
requirejs(['module'], function (module)  {
    return module;
});
```

Your **index.html** from **app1** then will be updated to in this way:

from something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="js/main" src="js/libs/require.js"></script>
```

to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="js/main" src="js/libs/require.js"></script>
<script>
    require(['module1']);
</script>
```

Then you may easy use app1/module in your second app.

I updated my [demo repository](https://github.com/shustariov-andrey/angularjs-requirejs) with this example. Check it out.

Comment: I probably didn't give enough details in my explanation. The module file was just an example but there may be any sort of files.  The key problem was that everything that happens in the file app1/main.js must use its own require config, so it can require files in its folder, while app2/main.js may use an entirely different config from its folder, but also be able to load the app1/main.js file. In your file, there is only one config file which will be used by both modules

Comment: @Malharhak Yes, I understood you. All you need to do is to separte concerns in your first module  in the way, that when you require it, its configuration was not required (that is what I described). Then ```app/module1``` may be just required in your second app.